# Is it possible to call a Windows Forms Keyboard in a Silverlight Web Application?

Tags: winforms, silverlight

I need a multilingual Keyboard for my Silverlight WebApplication. I have now written it with Windows.Forms and Sendkeys. It works fine.

Now the problem is that I want to call it inside from the Silverlight WebApplication with a Click Function on a Textbox or a button so when its pressed the Keyboard pops up. I thought about running the Windows.Forms Application in the Background and tried to FindWindow() with Silverlight but it did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about using winform. But, you can use win32 methods (so, I guess Winforms too) in Silverlight 5 using PInvoke

Comment: The WebApplication is written in Silverlight 3. So I have to use it too.